# Excel loop VBA macro copy incremental cell range to new sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make an Excel VB macro that takes the incremental cells in each column and copies it incrementally to a new sheets, to later be exported as a csv for statistical analysis in spss or jamovi.

For example, if I have data in A1:A50 and B1:B50, I would like to copy A1:A(i) & B1:B(i) to worksheet(i), i = i + 1, then copy the new range A1:A(i) & B1:B(i) to a new worksheet.

Something like this? (Modified from [Excel loop VBA Macro copy cells to new sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223364/excel-loop-vba-macro-copy-cells-to-new-sheet) and [Exporting Data into a CSV - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275943/exporting-data-into-a-csv-excel-vba))

```
Dim Static As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Temp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set Static = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WIP_List") 

i = 1 'initial value of i 

'Copies incremental range to new sheets
Do While IsEmpty(Static.Range("A" & i).Value) = False 'loops through

Set Temp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("set (" & i & ")")

Static.Range("A1" & : & "A" & i).Copy _
Destination:=Temp.Cell("A1")



'This part exports the worksheet as a csv

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
 PathName = "" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
ws.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

i = i + 1
Loop
```

The idea is that if I have N number of samples, it will create N number of worksheets with i + 1 number of rows for each.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Firstly, change `"A1" & : & "A"` to `"A1:A"` - that will at least get rid of the syntax error.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771525/convert-xlsx-to-csv-using-vba-script/44772070#44772070) convert  range to csv without new worksheet.